# htaccess rewrite url rule trouble detect $_GET isset

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about/([^/.]+)/?$ about.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have a page use htaccess rewrite rule for url

```
/about/33
```

the page require $_GET['id'] to fetch db

however i have trouble to detect GET variable isset

`if(isset($_GET['id'])){fetch data...}else{header("location:...");}`

if user only enter `/about/` without `$GET['id']` the page will not found instead run header("location");

is anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
RewriteRule ^about/([^/.]*)/?$ about.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Put * instead of +